# Is there any method to separate text into paragraphs of similar context

Tags: text-classification

I want to split my text that has various sentences of different context mixed into separate paragraphs of similar context.
for example, if my text is:

```
Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi, popularly known as Mahatma Gandhi, is regarded as the Father of Nation. 
Gandhi was a social reformist and leader of Indian Independence Movement who introduced the idea of non-violent resistance called Satyagrah. 
Global Warming is a phenomenon that is occurring every minute resulting in a gradual increase in the Earth’s overall climate. 
Brought about by greenhouse gases that trap the solar radiation in the atmosphere, global warming can change the entire map of the earth, displacing areas, flooding many countries and destroying multiple lifeforms. 
Extreme weather is a direct consequence of global warming but it is not an exhaustive consequence. There are virtually limitless effects of global warming which are all harmful to life on earth.The sea level is increasing by 0.12 inches per year worldwide. 
Gandhi was born in Gujarat and studied law at the Inner Temple, London. After organising a civil disobedience movement for Indians living in South Africa, he returned to India in 1915. In India, he set out on a train journey to different parts of the country trying to understand problems of farmers, peasants and urban labourers and organising protests for them. He assumbed the leadership of Indian National Congress in 1921 and rose to become its most prominent leader and an iconic figure in Indian politics. He organised the Dandi Salt March in 1930 and Quit India Movement in 1942. He also worked for the upliftment of untouchables and have them a new name 'Harijan' meaning the children of God. Gandhi also wrote extensively for various newspapers and his symbol of self-reliance - the spinning wheel - became a popular symbol of Indian Independence Movement. Gandhi played a key role in pacifying people and averting the Hindu-Muslim riots as tensions rose before and during the partition of the country. He was shot dead by Nathuram Godse on January 31, 1948.Stress management is a wide spectrum of techniques and psychotherapies aimed at controlling a person's level of stress, especially chronic stress, usually for the purpose of and for the motive of improving everyday functioning. 
This is happening because of the melting of polar ice caps because of global warming. This has increased the frequency of floods in many lowland areas and has caused damage to coral reefs. The Arctic is one of the worst hit areas affected by global warming. 
Air quality has been adversely affected and the acidity of the seawater has also increased causing severe damage to marine life forms. Severe natural disasters are brought about by global warming which has had dire effects on life and property.
Stress produces numerous physical and mental symptoms which vary according to each individual's situational factors.These can include a decline in physical health as well as depression. The process of stress management is named as one of the keys to a happy and successful life in modern society. Life often delivers numerous demands that can be difficult to handle, but stress management provides a number of ways to manage anxiety and maintain overall well-being.
```

After processing I want:

````
Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi, popularly known as Mahatma Gandhi, is regarded as the Father of Nation. 
Gandhi was a social reformist and leader of Indian Independence Movement who introduced the idea of non-violent resistance called Satyagrah. 
Gandhi was born in Gujarat and studied law at the Inner Temple, London. After organising a civil disobedience movement for Indians living in South Africa, he returned to India in 1915. In India, he set out on a train journey to different parts of the country trying to understand problems of farmers, peasants and urban labourers and organising protests for them. He assumbed the leadership of Indian National Congress in 1921 and rose to become its most prominent leader and an iconic figure in Indian politics. He organised the Dandi Salt March in 1930 and Quit India Movement in 1942. He also worked for the upliftment of untouchables and have them a new name 'Harijan' meaning the children of God. Gandhi also wrote extensively for various newspapers and his symbol of self-reliance - the spinning wheel - became a popular symbol of Indian Independence Movement. Gandhi played a key role in pacifying people and averting the Hindu-Muslim riots as tensions rose before and during the partition of the country. He was shot dead by Nathuram Godse on January 31, 1948.

Global Warming is a phenomenon that is occurring every minute resulting in a gradual increase in the Earth’s overall climate. 
Brought about by greenhouse gases that trap the solar radiation in the atmosphere, global warming can change the entire map of the earth, displacing areas, flooding many countries and destroying multiple lifeforms. 
Extreme weather is a direct consequence of global warming but it is not an exhaustive consequence. There are virtually limitless effects of global warming which are all harmful to life on earth.The sea level is increasing by 0.12 inches per year worldwide. 
This is happening because of the melting of polar ice caps because of global warming. This has increased the frequency of floods in many lowland areas and has caused damage to coral reefs. The Arctic is one of the worst hit areas affected by global warming. 
Air quality has been adversely affected and the acidity of the seawater has also increased causing severe damage to marine life forms. Severe natural disasters are brought about by global warming which has had dire effects on life and property.

Stress management is a wide spectrum of techniques and psychotherapies aimed at controlling a person's level of stress, especially chronic stress, usually for the purpose of and for the motive of improving everyday functioning. 
Stress produces numerous physical and mental symptoms which vary according to each individual's situational factors.
 These can include a decline in physical health as well as depression. The process of stress management is named as one of the keys to a happy and successful life in modern society. 
Life often delivers numerous demands that can be difficult to handle, but stress management provides a number of ways to manage anxiety and maintain overall well-being.
```
````

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I think that this is called [topic segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation#Topic_segmentation).

Comment: okay thanks, but is there any where I can find the code to test?

Comment: I don't know. As far as I know it's not a common task for, there might not be any standard implementation.